Read a SQL dump created with pg_dump
I have a PostgreSQL dump file that was created by an automated command line on a Linux server:
docker exec my-container pg_dump my-database -Fc -U postgres > my-db.gzip

I've been trying the following to uncompress the resulting file:

to uncompress the file with gzip -d my-db.gzip but I get unknown suffix -- ignored
to rename the file my-db.gz and then gzip -d my-db.gzip but I get not in gzip format
to rename the file my-db.tar.gz and then tar -xf my-db.tar.gz but I get tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format

I'm confused. Any clue what is the exact format created by pg_dump -Fc and how I can uncompress it?

It's a pgdump file not a tarball or gzipped, why do you think so? You can only extract it using pg_restore https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html I'm not sure why you would think otherwise? -Fc is documented as "
Output a custom-format archive suitable for input into pg_restore. Together with the directory output format, this is the most flexible output format in that it allows manual selection and reordering of archived items during restore. This format is also compressed by default." Just because you call it `.gzip` doesn't make it a gzip.


I thought "-c" meant "compressed". Indeed It's actually an uncompressed dump file. Thanks

No it's compressed, just not with gzip.  "This format is also compressed by default." If yo uwanted gzip it's not clear which underlying format you wanted: Plain SQL or Directory or tarball

pg_restore -f my-db.sql my-db.zip . This will produce a plain text version of the compressed file as the file my-db.sql.  You need to spend time reading the docs pg_dump and pg_restore.

So I can open it with a pg_restore, all good, but part of my original question still remains, what's the compression algorithm behind "-Fc"?
